# C3#, Unity - Input.GetKeyDown in OnCollisionEnter not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision

Here's what I have for my 3D code, on my Player. Debug.Log() does not print to console, nor does any other output.

```
    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if(collision.gameObject.tag = "Enemy" && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            Debug.Log("Working");
        }
    }
```

Very simple code and I cannot find out what's wrong with it.

When I get rid of "&& Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)" it works perfectly. Yes, I'm colliding with another GameObject tagged "Enemy", and my Player has Rigidbody attached. They're not positive for IsTrigger. I've even tried Input.GetKeyDown("space") instead of the KeyCode.

Comment: You can't rely on getting the input within OnCollisionEnter, keep a flag in update method like `spaceButtonPressed = Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)` and use that variable instead.

Answer (score 0):

pretty unlikely that you manage to press down the key exactly in the same frame as the collision is detected!

Rather do e.g.

```
private GameObject currentEnemy;

private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if(collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy"))
    {
        currentEnemy = collision.gameObject;
    }
}

private void OnCollisionExit(Collision collision)
{
    if(collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy") && collision.gameObject == currentEnemy)
    {
        currentEnemy = null;
    }
}

private void Update()
{
    if(currentEnemy && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        Debug.Log($"Working, interacting with {currentEnemy}");
    }
}
```